# I can't access the login screen in Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (2)

Tags: boot, 16.04, lubuntu, xorg, login-screen

Sorry for repeat the same thread but nobody answer me and I need a fix as soon as posible because I can't stay updating PCs going first to 15.10 and later to the LTS. Please help me! Thanks in advance!

**This is the original message.**

I have a Toshiba NB300 with 1 GB RAM with Intel® Atom™ processor N450 and I recently installed Lubuntu 16.04 LTS i386 and I have this message on the screen instead of the login box

```
/dev/sda6: clean, 124768/2379216 files, 881581/9509376 blocks
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the `fsck-on-boot` thing, I think. Wait, and the login screen should appear - I see that message everytime I boot up.

Comment: I wait for more than 10 minutes. I can skip that message if I update from 15.10 to the LTS but I can't skip it in the fresh install

Comment: Again without answer... I don't know what can I do... I think that the only fix for me will be install 15.10 and opt for LTS...

Comment: Please help!!!! T.T

Comment: please provide the output of `systemctl status lightdm.service` try to `systemctl enable lightdm.service`

Comment: I'm pretty new with Lubuntu and all the internal stuff. Can you tell me what i need to found in a more specific way? Now I have this version of Lubuntu upgraded from 15.10 and now I can work but I need to do a clean install :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I fixed this problem using these steps:

1. Boot to GRUB (press SHIFT until the menu is shown).
2. Go to recovery.
3. Resume normal boot.
4. The computer will boot but with bad resolution.
5. Go to terminal and run this command:

   ```
   apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
   ```
6. Reboot, and everything will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the error by pressing SHIFT button when booting, go to the recovery mode and then resume to normal boot, you will get an xorg error but you can close that window.

But that is no fix because you have to do it every time you boot and you'll face many error (deformed wallpaper, bad resolution, can't change the refresh rate)

I hope someone can provide a permanent working solution, because this release is fast and it will be shame not to use it because of an stupid error.

Comment: we need more debug information to provide a solution. Maybe you are missing some drivers?

Comment: is xorg enabled?

Comment: We aren't missing any drivers. This is a Lubuntu OS problem. I have the same problem on a HP Compaq TC4400